# Mapnik: Can you draw outline/ strokes on Polygon geometries?

Tags: mapnik

My data consists of a lot of polygons which need to be outlined. Unfortunately I cannot find any option on the **PolygonSymbolizer** - and my **LineSymbolizer** seems to be without effect. Here is my stylesheet with the important parts being in ll3-4:

```
<Map background-color="transparent">
    <Style name="productStyle1">
        <LineSymbolizer stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"/>
        <PolygonSymbolizer fill-opacity="1" fill="#868CFF"/>
    </Style>
    <Layer name="productlayer">
        <StyleName>productStyle1</StyleName>
    </Layer>
</Map>
```

Is it not possible to draw outlines on polygons in Mapnik?

Comment: I cannot find what's wrong with your mapnik xml. It is indeed possible to combine LineSymbolizer, PolygonSymbolizer and even others symbolizers in the same style.

Comment: I forgot to wrap it inside <Rule></Rule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to wrap it inside `<Rule></Rule>`       attribute